# Kotlin: data class private setter public getter

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way I can make a private setter and a public getter in a Kotlin Data Class?

```
data class Test(var attribute: String) {

    // attribute can be mutated inside this class

    // but outside only readable ?
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A simple approach would be to have a private var, but then to provide a public property that delegates to it:

```
data class Test (private var attribute_ : String) {
  val attribute: String get() = attribute_
}
```

Comment: ...except this does not work in my case because the field needs to be reachable by XStream, hmpf

Answer (score 14):

To add some background to the other answer:

There's no way to do this directly in the constructor, though there have been several proposals as to how it could be added to the language; see [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/private-setter-for-var-in-primary-constructor/3640/22).

If it weren't a data class, I'd suggest this alternative:

```
class Test(_attribute: String) {
    var attribute = _attribute
        private set
}
```

That only stores one value in the object, so is marginally more efficient.

But since this is a data class, that's not possible.  (Data classes can't have non-properties in their primary constructors.)  So the other answer's suggestion seems best.

Comment: Thanks for the background. Thats what I would love to see in Kotlins Data classes: to have non-properties in their primary constructor it