# Is it possible to encapsulate open and override variables to prevent direct access from main() function while implementing inheritance in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, overriding, visibility, encapsulation

My code -

```
fun main() {
    val student = Student()
    student.greet()
}

open class Person(open var name: String) {
    fun greet() {
        println("Hello $name")
    }
}

class Student(override var name: String = "John Doe"): Person(name) {

}
```

Here I have a `parent` `class` `Person` and a `child` `class` `Student`. `parent` `class` `Person` has `property` `name` and `method` `greet()`. `child` `class` `Student` is `inheriting` them.

Here I am able to directly modify `name` `variable` of `Student` `class` from `main()` `function` using `student.name`. I want to `encapsulate` `name` `variable` to prevent `name` from being directly modified from `main()` `function` so that the `constructor` `Student()` is the only way to set the value of `name` `variable`.

Usually `private` `visibility modifier` `keyword` is used to `encapsulate` `variables` in a `class`.
But apparently when the `variables` have `open` or `override` `modifier`, this technique does not work.

So, is it possible to `encapsulate` `name` `variable`?

Comment: Remove open var and var

Comment: you can use both solutions from this qustion to make `name` unmodifiable from outside the class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351124/kotlin-data-class-private-setter-public-getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `open` keyword, and call the `Person`'s constructor to set it instead of overriding it from Student (which is also null-prone at the init block of Person, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735604/kotlin-init-block-in-super-class-firing-with-null-properties-when-inheriting-fro)):

```kotlin
open class Person(private var _name: String) {
    val name get() = _name

    fun greet() {
        println("Hello $name")
    }
}

class Student(name: String = "John Doe"): Person(name) {

}
```

Comment: Here I am getting error in `student.greet()` in `main()` `function`. Error --> Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public final fun greet(): Unit defined in sampleInheritance.Student

Comment: you cannot use inheritance without `open`, classes are final by default

Comment: that's my question, is it possible to implement both inheritance and encapsulation together?

Comment: @IR42 in that case `name` `variable` can be modified directly from `main()` `function` using `student.name`. I cannot achieve `encapsulation`. But `encapsulation` is always desired in any programming

Comment: @PayelSenapati Ah I actually misunderstood the problem at first. I've updated it. This will delegate getter function of `name` to return the `_name`.